# DataGridView remove row which constains exe extensions

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview which store a path to files with extensions and I must delete rows which are .exe extensions.

My Code:

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewgrida.Rows)
                        {
                            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(".exe"))
                                row.Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            dataGridViewgrida.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridViewgrida.Rows.); // ?? I do not know how to do this

                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use reverse loop and delete row based on index:

```
for(int i=dataGridViewgrida.Rows.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
    var row = dataGridViewgrida.Rows[i];
    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(".exe"))
    {
        dataGridViewgrida.Rows.RemoveAt(i); // or dataGridViewgrida.Rows.Remove(row );
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to remove an item from a collection you're currently iterating over. Put the current `row` into a temporary collection and remove them *after* your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove items from the collecion when you are looping it. Create a list to keep the rows you need to delete a populate it inside the loop.
Then you can remove them in another loop:

```
foreach(DataGridRow row in yourList) 
   dataGridViewgrida.Rows.Remove(item);
```